# Changing an Element's `backgroundImage` at run time interferes with Class properties

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

I change my background of a `div` at run time:

```
 this.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/back.jpg')";
```

However, previously it's class was set in css:

```
.myMainDiv {width: 100%;height: 100%;min-height: 100vh;background-color: #000000;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;}
```

When I had a larger picture, it worked fine. However, when I reduced the dimensions of the background picture to save a bit of memory, it then stretch the picture fully across the screen as it should, but repeated the picture 3 times down the height.

What on earth would have caused this?

Comment: can you share reproduce-able code?

Comment: In your css rule, it contains the no-repeat, which you would need to add to js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works as you want (the background would be a grey placeholder if it wasn't updated). The image is poor quality because I've asked it to only be 120px square.

I also changed the height of `.myMainDiv` to make sure it's height was larger than the placeholder, and set `width: 120px;` to ensure the placeholder should repeat vertically if `background-repeat: no-repeat;` wasn't working.

**Update** all the styles have been stored in a string, so that you can apply this as and when you wish via JS. This will override all other CSS styles specific to that element (but not those from classes, etc) so you do need to be a little careful.

```js
cssAllStyles = "min-height: 100vh; background-color: #000000; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;"


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myMainDiv');
var requiredElement = elements[0];

requiredElement.style.cssText = cssAllStyles + "background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/120/120/any')";
```

```css
.myMainDiv {
  width: 120px;
  height: 300px; 
  background-image: url('"https://via.placeholder.com/150');
 }
```

```html
<div class="myMainDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This looks good, but I do not see what I am doing differently to you.

Comment: It may depend on how you are defining `this` but you haven't provided that bit of code... Try using the code I've provided and see if it works with your code.

Comment: Yes, it works when I am not doing anything too complicated, but when I put it in my code which is a bit involved, it just goes wrong. Thanks for the help though. It turns out @nocturns2 was right in the comments of the OP. I have to reset all the class stuff separately, eg `requiredElement.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";` Do you know if there is any quick way of resetting all these? I tried `requiredElement.className = requiredElement.className;` but that did not work.

Comment: Yep, you can store the styles in a string and then apply this to the `cssText` of the element. I've left the `background-image` value out in case you need this to vary. Obviously you can move some of these values into the styles if you prefer.